# python - convert datetime to varchar/string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pass a parameter to a `pyodbc` query but the field is not a datetime field. When I set the parameter manually to `2016-08-31`, the query works. When I pass it a datetime variable, it fails.

Can I somehow convert a datetime variable to a varchar/string before passing the parameter into the `connection.execute("SELECT xxx FROM xxx WHERE x=?", myParam)`?

Using linux and odbc-driver `freetds`. Data source is ms sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `strftime` method from `datetime` package. For example

```
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.now()
date_str = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

---

In case of you would need to make date from string this way you should use `strptime` (reverse method)

```
d = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: This worked and then revealed other problems with my code xD. I accidentally had both 'import datetime' and from 'datetime import datetime' which caused problems....

Answer (score 1):

You can format the datetime as you requested with

```
datetimevariable.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dt = datetime.datetime.now()
dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Then insert `dt` into the query.